# Using Nginx to redirect to dynamic host

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I've used Nginx as a load balancer and reverse proxy with success, but this issue which seems really simple has tripped me up. I've spent a few hours on trying to configure Nginx but have failed.

I have a dynamic set of servers/hostnames (because of using docker), say service2, service3, service5. I simply want to configure nginx to proxy to these based on the URL. The purpose of this is so i can access the services from a single endpoint rather than expose them all.

This is the type of proxy I'm trying to get working

- http://localhost:8009/service2 => http://service2:80
- http://localhost:8009/service5/home => http://service5:80/home
- http://localhost:8009/service5/home?action=something => http://service5:80/home?action=something

If i specify all endpoints it works, although still only for the initial page, so http://localhost:8009/service2 do proxy to http://service2/ however http://localhost:8009/service2/home just fails but this would be because it's failing to match a location. If if i just do location / it works, then i can only reverse proxy all requests to a single server.

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

    location /service2 {
        proxy_pass http://service2/;
    }

    location /service5 {
        proxy_pass http://service5/;
    }
}
```

Here is probably my best example of regexing the url to be dynamic, but this just errors so assume it's not valid for nginx.

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

    location ~ (?<myhost>.*)/(?<myuri>.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://$myhost/$myuri;
    }
}
```

Comment: @CalumHalpin Nginx supports named captures just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure how Nginx resolves the `service2` and `service5` names. If it needs to use DNS, you may need to define a [`resolver` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) when using `proxy_pass` with a variable. You captures do not include the query string (as they are not present on the `location` regex), but you might be able to use `proxy_pass http:/$request_uri;` instead, as that variable already includes the string `/serviceX/...`.

Comment: @RichardSmith i've added a resolve see answer below, but still having issues. it does change the behaviour slightly so its detected something but still not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

The regex that you are using is not the correct one. you can achieve what you are trying to do in the following way

```
 location ~ /(?<myhost>[^/]+)(/(?<myuri>.*))? {
      return 301 http://$myhost:80/$myuri?$query_string;
    }
```

```
➜  ~   curl --head http://127.0.0.1:32769/service1
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.17.8
Date: Sun, 23 Feb 2020 20:06:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://service1:80/?

➜  ~   curl --head http://127.0.0.1:32769/service1/test
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.17.8
Date: Sun, 23 Feb 2020 20:08:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://service1:80/test?

➜  ~   curl --head http://127.0.0.1:32769/service1/test?x=100
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.17.8
Date: Sun, 23 Feb 2020 20:08:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://service1:80/test?x=100
```

for `proxy_pass` you don't need to include the URI or the query strings, you can do it like this

```
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;

    location ~ /(?<myhost>[^/]+) {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

        set $target http://$myhost:80;

        proxy_set_header Host $myhost;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass $target;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. The first one that does "return 301", does a redirect. So it redirects from http://localhost:8009 onto http://service5 this fails, as service5 isn't exposed, so it needs to be a proxy. So i tried your second answer, and the errors logs say the following.

Comment: 2020/02/23 17:45:19 [error] 6#6: *2 no resolver defined to resolve service38, client: 172.28.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /service38 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8009"
172.28.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2020:17:45:19 +0000] "GET /service38 HTTP/1.1" 502 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: This was for calling http://localhost:8009/service38 where i expected the proxy to get the data from http://service38/ behind the scenes . I can call service38 using curl from the nginx container, but service38 isn't available directly from my machine, hence the need for a proxy.

Comment: the proxy pass will work only if Nginx can resolve and can reach 'service38'. do you host these services in docker? and are these the service names?

Comment: Correct, they are all hosted in docker and on the same network. These are the service names whilst i test out this approach. They are all just blank .net core websites at the moment. So nginx exposes port 80 as localhost:8009, service38, service39 run on port 80, but are not exposed on localhost. So the only way to access them will be via the nginx container. I'm run "curl service38" and it outputs a response from that container so nginx can see it.

Comment: I updated the Nginx configs with the resolver, can you try that?

Comment: I've updated the config, and below is the output. I understand why 127.0.0.11 is needed is that's the docker DNS. Where a hostname exists, say service38 and service39 it returns 404, but for something else that does not exist says service40. It redirect my browser to my ISP (virgin media in my case, and does a search for a page not found).

Comment: 172.28.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020:21:45:39 +0000] "GET /service38 HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"

172.28.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020:21:45:49 +0000] "GET /service40 HTTP/1.1" 200 910 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: What ill do next time im on, i'll setup a docker compose file with 3 blank websites (services) + nginx so it can be replicated by anyone.